# Vue model is not working and doesn't perform the function

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.5, input-field, v-model

This is my form file and it includes the VUE input-field, I want to only show that field only when I checked that option **Manually set new password**. That is the last field where the issue is present.

```js
      var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
          password_options: 'keep'
        }
        computed: {
          canShowThis() {
            return ['auto', 'manual'].includes(this.password_options)
          }
        }
      });
```

```html
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    
    <div class="field">
        <label for="password" class="label">Password</label>
        <p class="control">
            <b-radio-group v-model="password_options">
                <div class="field">
                    <b-radio name="password_options" value="keep" selected>
                        Do Not Change Password
                    </b-radio>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <b-radio name="password_options" value="auto">
                        Auto Generate New Password
                    </b-radio>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <b-radio name="password_options" value="manual">
                        Manually Set New Password
                    </b-radio>
                    <p class="control">
                        <input type="text" class="input m-b-10 m-t-10" name="password" id="password"
                               v-if="canShowThis" placeholder="Manually give a password to this user">
                    </p>
                </div>
            </b-radio-group>
        </p>
    </div>
    
    <button class="button is-primary">
        <i class="fa fa-refresh m-r-10"></i>Update User
    </button>
```

Comment: Might be minor but there is a comma `,` missing before the `computed:` in your JS. Maybe that just breaks the execution of the method...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem lies here?

> v-model will ignore the initial value, checked or selected attributes found on any form elements. It will always treat the Vue instance data as the source of truth. You should declare the initial value on the JavaScript side, inside the data option of your component.

Or

> If the initial value of your v-model expression does not match any of the options, the  element will render in an “unselected” state. On iOS this will cause the user not being able to select the first item because iOS does not fire a change event in this case. It is therefore recommended to provide a disabled option with an empty value.

So, if you initialized the 'password_options' to 'keep', also make this option as selected in you form:

```html
<div class="field">
  <b-radio value="keep" selected>Do Not Change Password</b-radio>
</div>
```

And give to the other options same `name` attribute:

```html
<div class="field">
  <b-radio name="password_options" value="keep">Do Not Change Password</b-radio>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <b-radio name="password_options" value="auto">Auto Generate New Password</b-radio>
</div>
```

Look for this demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    option: 'val1'
  },
  computed: {
    canShowThis () {
      return ['val3', 'val4'].includes(this.option)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <input name="group" type="radio" v-model="option" value="val1" selected>
  <input name="group" type="radio" v-model="option" value="val2">
  <input name="group" type="radio" v-model="option" value="val3">
  <input name="group" type="radio" v-model="option" value="val4" v-if="canShowThis">
  <p>Selected option value: {{ option }}</p>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
```

```html
<div class="field">
  <label for="password" class="label">Password</label>
  <p class="control">
    <b-radio-group>
      <div class="field">
        <b-radio name="password_options" value="keep" selected v-model="password_options">
          Do Not Change Password
        </b-radio>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <b-radio name="password_options" value="auto" v-model="password_options">
          Auto Generate New Password
        </b-radio>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <b-radio name="password_options" value="manual" v-model="password_options">
          Manually Set New Password
        </b-radio>
        <p class="control">
          <input
            type="text"
            class="input m-b-10 m-t-10"
            name="password"
            id="password"
            v-if="canShowThis"
            placeholder="Manually give a password to this user"
          >
        </p>
      </div>
    </b-radio-group>    
  </p>
</div>

<button class="button is-primary">
  <i class="fa fa-refresh m-r-10"></i>Update User
</button>

<script>
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      password_options: 'keep'
    }
    computed: {
      canShowThis () {
        return this.password_options === 'manual'
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I don`t want it selected, I want that when I click on the Manually Set New Password, I want to open an input field which is not opening

Comment: @MuhammadHamza I added the example. Is this behaviour what you need?

Comment: Yes! I need this when I click on the last radio button, Manually set new password I want to open the input field

Comment: I did, but it permanently open the field after refresh the page not on clicking the radio button

Comment: @MuhammadHamza Hm... Edit your question with current version of html and js.

Comment: Yes! I changed it

Comment: @MuhammadHamza Great! :) So, now you can accept my answer :)

Comment: I changed it exactly as you told and I also edited it above, but the problems stills there. It don`t resolve. Even the radio buttons gone away, and field is also showing with the three above texts

Comment: @MuhammadHamza I added new code. Copy and paste it to your project - replace your existing code and try if it works.

Comment: Leave it buddy, it doesn`t work. You tried a lot. Thanks Although

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your problem correctly. Here is a way how to show/hide input field with radio button.

Initiate function "toggleField" on radio button check:

```html
<b-radio name="password_options" value="manual" @change-value="toggleField">
    Manually Set New Password
</b-radio>
```

Initiate toggle variable:

```js
data: function() {
  return {
    toggle: false
  }
```

Create a method that would toggle it's value:

```js
methods: {
  toggleField() {
    this.toggle = !this.toggle;
  },
```

Wrap the input field in div tag and add v-if statement:

```html
<div v-if="toggle === true">
    <p class="control">
        <input type="text" class="input" name="password"
               id="password" v-if="password_options == 'manual'"
               placeholder="Manually give a password to this user">
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I might be able to help you, can you setup a jfiddle with a sniplet of your code? I tried it, but also failed to recreate radio buttons.

Comment: Nope, I can`t. But without using that. I can`t access it ?

Comment: @MuhammadHamza, you're using the ` character instead of ' and it's badly messing your text style format.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just mentioning the mistake that I have made which resulted in the same problem.

I used **:v-model** instead of **v-model**

Kindly check if **v-model** has been used.

May be it will help someone who had done the same mistake as mine.